# Angular still compiled without error even after explicitly casting a number into a string variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am currently learning the very first topics of angular.. Unfortunately I have already encountered an unusual scenario.. Like this

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
 selector: 'sandbox',
 template: `
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>`
 })
 export class SanboxComponent {  
   name:string = "John Doe";  //name is declared as string
   constructor() {
     this.name = 34; //this should be the error..
   }
 }
```

However, on my browser, it still outputs "Hello 34".

I know javascript, but this is also my first encounter with typescript. According to my understanding, the name:string should only accept a string as a value. Can someone explain what happened here?

Comment: Tested on my side, it seems that it lints an error, as a warning, but it stills working.
`Type '34' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Answer (score 0):

By default, TypeScript transpiler will returns you a warning, but transpilation will continue, even with the type error.

If you want to be more accurate, and prevent transpiler working with type errors, you can edit your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmitOnError": true,
    }
}
```

Set `noEmitOnError` on `true`.

Answer (score 0):

When your app is run, it is compiled to JavaScript, where there is no type checking, therefore it runs without error. The power of TypeScript is the typing, and is that the IDE keeps track of the type checking for you and can **warn** about type mismatching errors you are making, for example here assigning a number to a variable you have declared as string. Therefore **always** avoid declaring things of type `any` (not that you are doing it here) as it just defeats the "purpose" of TypeScript.

So short answer is, TypeScript doesn't exist on runtime, it's just plain JS, therefore no runtime errors :)